# Returning multidimensional array c++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, return

I want to create a function that returns a C-style multidimensional array
`int mArray[2][2];
int[][] mArray getArray();`

so this does not work, and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if you fiddle around and get the right syntax, you can't have a built-in array as a return type.

Comment: It may help this question if you explain your ultimate goal.  Are you trying to trying to return a "grid" of `int`s?  Are you trying to implement an interface that's C-compatible?  Are you interested in learning about the dusty corners of C++ syntax?

Comment: I cannot upvote @DrewDormann 's comment enough. Even if what you are asking is impossible, there are almost always alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

From [dcl.funct]:

> **Functions shall not have a return type of type array** or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things. There shall be no arrays of functions, although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

You can, however, return a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> getArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return arrays by value because they do not copy implicitly (and because the standard says so). You should use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
std::array<std::array<int,2>,2> fun();
std::array<std::array<int,2>,2> arr = fun();
```

There are not many reasons to use C-arrays over `std::array` nowadays, with the most common one probably being "because my teacher/prof/boss says so".